Add custom plugin to another Kotlin project
I've got two projects:

First project is Kotlin Plugin that generates some code.
Second project is Kotlin project in Spring, it imports above plugin and automatically runs before build.

I want to add my plugin to Spring project, so:

I'm uploading my plugin with ./gradlew clean publishToMavenLocal command.
I've added following configuration in settings.gradle.kts in Spring project:

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}


I've run ./gradlew clean build and I've got following error:

Unable to determine constructor argument #1: value org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.() -> kotlin.Unit not assignable to type ObjectFactory.
I'm a bit confused, I do not know what's the source of problem. I'm wondering if it's related to double id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.23" plugin and classpath problem.
Plugin build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.9.23"
    id("maven-publish")
    id("java-gradle-plugin")
}

group = "com.example"
version = "1.0.0"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(gradleApi())
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.9.23")
    implementation("org.openapitools:openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:7.4.0")
}

kotlin {
    jvmToolchain(21)
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("interfaceGeneratorOpenApi") {
            id = "interface-generator-open-api-test"
            implementationClass = "com.example.plugin.openapi.OpenApiGeneratorPlugin"
        }
    }
}

Spring project build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.23"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.23"
    id("interface-generator-open-api-test") version "1.0.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
}

group = "com.example.be"
version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
    implementation("org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.5.0")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "21"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}


Are you running ./gradlew clean build in your plugin project? Looks like an error building the code of your plugin.

@SimonJacobs indeed It was, i tried to run task with type X and action returning task of type Y. Description is a little bit weird, thanks
